# How to call a function inside another function but in a different shell

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, functions

I have a shell script with two functions. The second function needs to be run as another user from a new bash shell. The first function is invoked into the second one. Function 1 uses some of the script variables.

```
#!/bin/bash
foo=bar
function1() {
    echo -e "$1"
}

function2() {
    echo "This is function2"
    function1 "I use function1"
    echo "I also need to print ${foo}"
}
export -f function2
su username -c "/bin/bash -c function2"
```

Actually this run function2 inside a new shell then fail to find neither function1 nor foo.

Is there a way to inject or pass them to the new function ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a job for separate script files, not functions.

`script1.sh`:

```
#! /bin/bash
echo -e "$1"
```

`script2.sh`:

```
#! /bin/bash
echo "This is script2"
bash script1.sh "I use script1"
echo "I also need to print ${foo}"
```

And `script.sh`:

```
#! /bin/bash
foo=bar
export foo
sudo -Eu username bash script2.sh
```

Forcing the use of functions here will lead to a hacky, unmaintainable solution. Don't.

Comment: I know it's dirty .. I just can't refactor my colleague scripts for now ( This is just an exemple , real scripts are way more complexe) .. I would be thankful if you can add a functions implementation to this.

Comment: @storm if it's complex, I'd recommend even more strongly: don't do it. Things will likely break. What you should do if you can't refactor is to run specific commands in `function2` with su or sudo.

Comment: Okay, that's fair enough thank you... I'll leave the question open in case someone have a handy solution.

Comment: @storm checkout `declare -f function1`, which will give you the `function1`'s declaration in reusable text. Then you could likely do something like `sudo -Eu username bash -c "$(declare -f function1 function2); function2"`

Comment: (I should say: ***somewhat*** reusable text. It will break with even slightly complex quoting. `printf "%q"` might help with that, but, eh...)

Comment: I agree this is far more complicated .. a late night refactoring is inescapable ...